# In Typescript, define a type for an array where the first element is more specific than the rest

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to define a type for an array whose first element is a specific type (e.g. Function), and the remaining elements are the empty type. For example:

```
type FAs = [Function, {}, {}, {}, ...]; // pseudo code
```

Is such a thing possible?

The purpose is to provide a single-argument function like this:

```
const myCaller = ([fun, ...args]: FAs) => fun.apply(args);
```

An alternative approach would be to use two arguments to `myCaller`, like this:

```
const myCaller = (fun: Function, args: any[]) => fun.apply(args);
```

but for aesthetic reasons I would prefer to use a single argument. I also wonder if the type system supports what is arguably an arbitrary-length tuple. Maybe such a thing is undesirable for computer science reasons I don't understand.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you define

```
type FAs = [Function, {}];
```

Then values of type `FAs` will require a first element of type `Function`, a second element of type `{}`, and succeeding elements of `Function | {}`. That is how TypeScript literal array types work. From the [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

> When accessing an element outside the set of known indices, a union type is used instead:

This should do everything you want **except** for the fact that you will be able to pass in a `Function`-typed value as the third element etc. of the array. But actually that would be the case anyway, since `Function` is compatible with `{}`.

There is no way around this. There is no way in TS to define an array type where the first *n* elements are of some specific type(s), and there are an arbitrary number of remaining elements of some other specific type.

> I also wonder if the type system supports what is arguably an arbitrary-length tuple.

Actually, the type system **only** supports arbitrary-length tuples. If you say

```
type Tuple = [number, number];
```

this type is compatible with any array, of length two **or greater**, that contains numbers. If you say

```
type Tuple = [string, number];
```

this type is compatible with any array, of length two **or longer**, that has a string as its first element, a number as its second, and either a string or number as its third etc. I would not call the reasons for this behavior "computer-science based"; it's more a matter of what it's feasible for TS to check.

## An alternate approach

```
interface Arglist {
  [index: number]: object;
  0: Function;
}

const a1: Arglist = [func];
const a2: Arglist = [22];                  // fails
const a3: Arglist = [func, "foo"];         // fails
const a4: Arglist = [func, obj];
const a5: Arglist = [func, obj, obj];
```

Comment: I had no idea Typescript would use a union type for elements outside the set of known indices, despite having read that documentation page multiple times. Thank you for the clear explanation and the link to the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me with Typescript 3.0.3.
When I declare a variable that uses this type, it complains that the lengths don't match.
As for the alternative approach, I want to use map, filter, etc. so had to amend the interface to include definitions for those.

Comment: @FTWinstone The `type` declarations above have an arbitrary length, requiring 2 or more elements in the resulting array. Also, the type of any elements after the second will not be restricted to `string|number` not just `number`. To get a type definition closer to the interface above, You could do `type myType = [string, ...number];` which means the first element must be a string and any other elements, *if any*, must be a number.

Comment: Looks like this answer is now outdated? There are [newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402096/in-typescript-define-a-type-for-an-array-where-the-first-element-is-more-specif/53119931#53119931) answers to this question, [including TypeScript 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402096/in-typescript-define-a-type-for-an-array-where-the-first-element-is-more-specif/62634698#62634698).

Comment: The statements about tuple types are now outdated. See [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) on tuples, which explicitly states that an error will be thrown if one tries to index past the length of the tuple.

Answer (score 68):

In current versions of Typescript this is possible using array spread:

`type FAs = [Function, ...Array<{}>]`

It supports any length from 1 to n (the first element is required).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want an `Array` with at least two elements the first one being of type `A` and all after that of type `B`.
A more general approach would be to define an intersection type as follow:

```js
type A = string
type B = number

// ensures that there are at least two elements
interface Foo {
  0: A;
  1: B;
}

// ensures that the first element is of type A and any after that of type B
type Bar = [A, ...B[]]

type MyArrayType = Foo & Bar

let a: MyArrayType

a = ['hello world', 1] // works
a = ['hello world', 1, 2] // works
a = ['hello world'] // fails
a = ['hello', 'world'] // fails
```

Note this works even if A is not a subset of B. Which would be required for the accepted answer to work.

I realize that this constraint was not required by the original question. But since I came across this thread with those constraints it might help someone else.

Answer (score 4):

> I also wonder if the type system supports what is arguably an arbitrary-length tuple.

Since TS 4.0, you can use [variadic tuple types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#variadic-tuple-types).
For example, assert `[func, ...<proper func args>]` in a type-safe way:

```
type FAs<A extends unknown[], R> = [(...args: A) => R, ...A]

const myCaller = <A extends unknown[], R>([fn, ...args]: FAs<A, R>) =>
    fn.apply(null, args)
```

Example:

```
const fn1 = (a1: string, a2: number) => true

const r1 = myCaller([fn1, "foo", 42]) // OK, r1 has type `boolean`
const r2 = myCaller([fn1, "foo", "bar"]) // error, `bar` has wrong type
const r3 = myCaller([fn1, "foo"]) // error, not enough arguments
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgggZwDxyhAHsCA7AJgqAV2wGtsB7Ad2wG0BdAGigCUA%20KAXihoAoA6AQEMATgHMEALihwAlJ3bMmAvnDoAoNQGNy2BMCgBbEAGFBAGzMRhnKCjSYc%20IqQrV6TNjxoAzbEqFiCHRS8MhwHqxyHKxqUHFQvnyCYGBmIDzYhBZMIuIyGgD0BWpFUACi6IIGqRAlxVo6egnYAIw2PIItUnrCAJbYojkATFKZBgBGVlHswMKEtQ26%20sJtXEamFlZevi1MAETe5OR7TAAsQ3RypQDyANJMK1AAFoIEoJBQAAbjR5aC2J9Fk1hEMbOtzJZhNtWvtDsd9uMRHtLlBSlZhORhExviJPs9XlBKBiBlB3rVtEsoMIAMxgkwQrY%20GFQA5HZFXApoYQYrFQCj6HDkQiiJ5QXKEAw4YAIIA)

Answer (score 3):

```js
type First<T> = T extends [infer U, ...any[]] ? U : any;
```

```js
type F = First<[number, boolean, string]> // number
```

Comment: can there be the reversed version `type Rest<T>`? `type F = Rest<[number, boolean, string]> // [boolean, string]`

Comment: @DilukaW `type Rest<T> = T extends [any, ...(infer R)[]] ? R : never`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the best you can do as of Typescript 2.3. You can see typings like this in lodash for example.

```
interface IMyCaller {
  <R>([fn]: [() => R]): R;
  <R,A>([fn, a]: [(a: A) => R, A]): R;
  <R,A,B>([fn, a, b]: [(a: A, b: B) => R, A, B]): R;
  <R,A,B,C>([fn, a, b, c]: [(a: A, b: B, c: C) => R, A, B, C]): R;
  // keep adding these until you get tired
}

const myCaller: IMyCaller = ([fun, ...args]) => fun.apply(args);
```

Comment: This is what I thought, also, but Typescript's use of union typing for elements not specifically defined is very helpful. Please see the accepted answer for an excellent description, along with one important caveat.

Comment: You're right, it can be helpful if you don't need strict typing. I guess I got carried away and didn't pay very close attention to your question :)