# Tuple with different type for last item (start with rest element first)

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I have a type `Foo` that is an `Array` that can contain any number of `Bar` elements, with an optional last `Qux` element.

Here are some examples of valid data:

```
[]
[bar]
[qux]
[bar, qux]
[bar, bar, bar, bar, bar]
[bar, bar, bar, qux]
```

Examples of invalid data:

```
[qux, qux]
[qux, bar]
[bar, bar, qux, bar]
[bar, bar, qux, qux]
```

Currently I have it as `type Foo = Array<Bar | Qux>`, but this does not capture the fact that only a single `Qux` is allowed, and only as the last item.

I'm not sure if I should even expect Typescript to be able to express this, or if there is any practical upside if it could be achieved.

Comment: Since rest elements must be last, I don't see a straightforward way to implement this. See [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25717) and [this ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1360) for more discussions on the matter. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53356755/1470607) might help with a convoluted solution.

Comment: @Nit Thank you, that is exactly the information I was looking for. If you post it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### TS 4.2

allows [leading/middle rest elements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2/#non-trailing-rests) in tuple types. You can now write:

```
type WithLastQux = [...Bar[], Qux]
```

To allow an *optional* last `Qux` (thanks @last-child):

```
type WithLastQux = [...Bar[], Qux] | Bar[]
```

Test:

```
// ok
const t11: WithLastQux = ["qux"]
const t12: WithLastQux = ["bar", "qux"]
const t13: WithLastQux = ["bar", "bar", "bar", "qux"]
const t14: WithLastQux = ["bar"]
const t15: WithLastQux = []

// error
const t16: WithLastQux = ["qux", "qux"] 
const t17: WithLastQux = ["qux", "bar"]
```

As extension, define a generic function helper to keep narrow, fixed-sized tuple types:

```
function foo<T extends WithLastQux>(t: T): T { return t }

foo(["bar", "qux"])
// type: function foo<["bar", "qux"]>(t: ["bar", "qux"]): ["bar", "qux"]
```

Note, that an *optional* last `Qux` element via `[...Bar[], Qux?]` is not directly possible:

> The only restriction is that a rest element can be placed anywhere in a tuple, so long as it’s not followed by another optional element or rest element. ([docs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-2/#non-trailing-rests))

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigIgEaLQbgFCiRQCKArgB4roCOFaB40A6gJbAAWAMnAM7BmVUAbQB0Y+AiEBdADQkKUqAB9YiaXjwB6TVAD2AazwBjXQDs+UYAEYrALiisO3PgKpC0tcminGzF6wBM9o5cvPwUbpjYch50PibmwJZWAMzBbKEuEcJRCGgxWHkF0TRxvonJACzpTmGuOYXe5f5WAKw1meGCUOpaOhAICLoIzUnWAGwdzl2RnvmlXoqjyQDsU3XZPbFexXk+fVAAggA2wAOmcMAsAG4Q9kYIEJfQAOYQpgMsRlAJfAhwLFMZwAJlAAGakUxGK5mKAHYC6KBgR48Aa3cEscgQYEAWh4LAAXtBgKQwMcIHJgWYAORJADuLGB70siMQ-xAeAhUJhpnBul0AB4ACpQCDkM6mYE8BwZaYCAB8AApgPYhQBKVVQADeUEeJIQvKSAF8NNo9IYwfzFdI1Zyre5GlJbZbdNbtt5nfbcvN3U67a6HSVvbsfXM-X0BkMRi63XMQ36Y+44wsPUA)

---

### TS 4.0

In JS, [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) always need to be the last function parameter. TS 4.0 comes with a feature called [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), which you can think of here as "rest parameters for types".

The neat thing is: variadic tuple types [can be placed anywhere](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#variadic-tuple-types) in function parameters, not just at the end. We now can define an arbitrary amount of `bar` items with an optional last element `qux`.

Example: `[bar, bar, <and arbitrary more>, qux]` can be interpreted as variadic tuple `[...T, qux]`, where `T` stands for all the `bar` items.

#### Solution 1: Separate `Assert` type

```
type Assert<T extends readonly (Bar | Qux)[]> =
    T extends readonly [] ? T :
    T extends readonly [...infer I, infer U] ?
    I extends [] ? T :
    I extends Bar[] ? T : readonly [...{ [K in keyof I]: Bar }, U] :
    never

function assert<T extends readonly (Bar | Qux)[] | readonly [Bar | Qux]>(
  a: Assert<T>): T { return a as T }

// OK
const ok1 = assert([])
const ok2 = assert(["bar"])
const ok3 = assert(["qux"])
const ok4 = assert(["bar", "qux"])
const ok5 = assert(["bar", "bar", "bar"])
const ok6 = assert(["bar", "bar", "bar", "qux"])

// errors
const err1 = assert(["qux", "qux"])
const err2 = assert(["qux", "bar"])
const err3 = assert(["bar", "bar", "qux", "bar"])
const err4 = assert(["bar", "bar", "qux", "qux"])
```

You might substitute the `assert` helper function with some kind of "sentinel" type:

```
type Sentinel<T, U extends T> = U
const arr1 = ["bar", "bar"] as const
const arr2 = ["qux", "bar"] as const
type Arr1Type = Sentinel<Assert<typeof arr1>, typeof arr1> // OK
type Arr2Type = Sentinel<Assert<typeof arr2>, typeof arr2> // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigIgEaLQKFJKARQFcAPFdARzNxwHo6oEI4ATAewDsAbEKYgM4RWUABYRmUAJacoAYzhCocKMGJhu0KQKhhFQkQDcpKgAaL5XAcFN5w0AIIChCYAB4AKlAilgETqw6zGxcvFAAFPBIAD5EZACUANoAugB8KDhQWVBePn4BQSwcPHwpUAD8OVAAXJnZub7%20gUxFoaUAdJ0yAGYSUACSADTSnL1IAKrJFXVZ-d6NBVBllV612QPz%20c1Ry1XVLSElS53tAN5LANIjUADWECDs3QPJ%201FQAL7DkzUzUJwQhgkODsBA8AAYKE4XO4UqkQdAPABGSHOCQwzDYNLwnIAJhR0LciTQ1FIaCx%20ARAGZ8WjCRiEGhhsSaOT7DkACw01x0rAMpm8xnoAWs0EAVi56IF-Ow0r5VBZcPojAAShAALZwMCqdSaKDGFSJE7nYLFMKJK4yW73R7PV6ID5fKbddhIDAQYB%20JASBAuqCsbQaOAgbFIgD6AFEEEhUFDaUSSYLmaSRQicRGoxK6QnZWS4RScpT09GoLHuUSpUKZfLSTmUxyi5ny1X6Yns9Xc8CGAdTaU3rESKQnS65BAdB4AMqqdgjMbajSj4aWhRKB7EP1cADkwH4SnMOjkVhsOG6xE4cmAUi4ylR3IaW0KhzCkXt-YSZViJraSz7cUHqXCcD7KW7geKk8T7F4py-MwagILIKgWB4ODvJ2jAAPIXDgB6cNYUDsDcyKoPoaLhCk8RYYeeE3HiRE3sApEtsk5HYbh%20HUrR0IMQmTEUTh274ZyHEkU2cpJmSzGUfh4pCa4DEVi2tYSXxVEAGwUMRskiYm8nydx5FKt4UYugIvG4d6hHXpx8Y0Eyemmdu3o0ZZwliYp9mGQg7HOZpCmVqJbaMUpZlRoJ3n0VpOa2TZ7Y8di47%20Be-zcJ4XybE0Y7pKg4zuYgCAWRFflktelh8TlUZOdZNaFVMFgscA2IOFGiIeGyqDxZwiUQMlwFuBSNq5YiqTDH1TwDXmbKNQgOItQQbUJTIXVuD1I3KOVQ2qPY-VrUAA)

#### Solution 2: Function overloading

```
type Bar = "bar"
type Qux = "qux"

function assert<T extends Bar[] = []>(
    arg: (Qux | Bar)[] extends [...T, Qux] ? never : [...T, Qux]): [...T, Qux]
function assert<T extends Bar[] = []>(arg: [...T]): [...T]
function assert<T extends Bar[] = []>(arg: [...T, Qux?]) { return arg }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigIgEaLQKFJKARQFcAPFdARzNxwDNiA7AY2AEsB7RqOAZ14gJgAHgAqUCKWARGAE16xEAbQC6FVQD4AFDih6eCAOYAuKFpLkAPooQBKVRKkz5UJQDoPogDREyagPxQjBAAboJQpu6ePhYqtpEebt6+pCr0TKyc3HwCQmKO0nIK8AgOqJpaiCauiaJxCZ5pDCzsXDz8giLikoUuJWWuKtpVDUkxZP5xUADeUAgQwMQI2UZQAL44OAD0W1AA8gDSOMxcvMBQHADWAIwUOZ1aqrbHp+dXAEx3HUKPmNhxL0YZwulwAzF9csBftRSGgAScgW9LgAWCEPJR-BBoHxoGFw54I4FXACsaJ+GKwWJxlOx6Bp8NeIIAbGSoRTsNSOXSubiaADtrtBAgOAheIDgULbqh7uTebCcXiGYiJAgEJ9pd82XLaZj8eLzkLwRrIb8aZyqVQaOa9YSDarUcb0brrQqrZbYXEgA)

---

### TS 3.9 and older

If you really need rest parameters followed by a last element (the specification only allows them to be last, see @Nit's answer), here is an alternative:

#### Assumptions

- A concrete array value is present and typed (e.g. `as const`)
- array size up to 256 elements (`StringToNumber` hardcoded size limit)
- You don't want to declare the `Bar`/`Qux` asserting type in a [recursive manner](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223): while technically possible, recursive types are not officially supported [till version 4.1](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) (*Note: updated*).

#### Code

```
type Bar = { bar: string };
type Qux = { qux: number };

// asserts Qux for the last index of T, other elements have to be Bar
type AssertQuxIsLast<T extends readonly any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]: StringToNumber[Extract<K, string>] extends LastIndex<T>
    ? T[K] extends Qux
      ? Qux
      : never
    : T[K] extends Bar
    ? Bar
    : never;
};

// = calculates T array length minus 1
type LastIndex<T extends readonly any[]> = ((...t: T) => void) extends ((
  x: any,
  ...u: infer U
) => void)
  ? U["length"]
  : never;

// TS doesn't support string to number type conversions ,
// so we support (index) numbers up to 256
export type StringToNumber = {
  [k: string]: number;
  0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67, 68: 68, 69: 69, 70: 70, 71: 71, 72: 72, 73: 73, 74: 74, 75: 75, 76: 76, 77: 77, 78: 78, 79: 79, 80: 80, 81: 81, 82: 82, 83: 83, 84: 84, 85: 85, 86: 86, 87: 87, 88: 88, 89: 89, 90: 90, 91: 91, 92: 92, 93: 93, 94: 94, 95: 95, 96: 96, 97: 97, 98: 98, 99: 99, 100: 100, 101: 101, 102: 102, 103: 103, 104: 104, 105: 105, 106: 106, 107: 107, 108: 108, 109: 109, 110: 110, 111: 111, 112: 112, 113: 113, 114: 114, 115: 115, 116: 116, 117: 117, 118: 118, 119: 119, 120: 120, 121: 121, 122: 122, 123: 123, 124: 124, 125: 125, 126: 126, 127: 127, 128: 128, 129: 129, 130: 130, 131: 131, 132: 132, 133: 133, 134: 134, 135: 135, 136: 136, 137: 137, 138: 138, 139: 139, 140: 140, 141: 141, 142: 142, 143: 143, 144: 144, 145: 145, 146: 146, 147: 147, 148: 148, 149: 149, 150: 150, 151: 151, 152: 152, 153: 153, 154: 154, 155: 155, 156: 156, 157: 157, 158: 158, 159: 159, 160: 160, 161: 161, 162: 162, 163: 163, 164: 164, 165: 165, 166: 166, 167: 167, 168: 168, 169: 169, 170: 170, 171: 171, 172: 172, 173: 173, 174: 174, 175: 175, 176: 176, 177: 177, 178: 178, 179: 179, 180: 180, 181: 181, 182: 182, 183: 183, 184: 184, 185: 185, 186: 186, 187: 187, 188: 188, 189: 189, 190: 190, 191: 191, 192: 192, 193: 193, 194: 194, 195: 195, 196: 196, 197: 197, 198: 198, 199: 199, 200: 200, 201: 201, 202: 202, 203: 203, 204: 204, 205: 205, 206: 206, 207: 207, 208: 208, 209: 209, 210: 210, 211: 211, 212: 212, 213: 213, 214: 214, 215: 215, 216: 216, 217: 217, 218: 218, 219: 219, 220: 220, 221: 221, 222: 222, 223: 223, 224: 224, 225: 225, 226: 226, 227: 227, 228: 228, 229: 229, 230: 230, 231: 231, 232: 232, 233: 233, 234: 234, 235: 235, 236: 236, 237: 237, 238: 238, 239: 239, 240: 240, 241: 241, 242: 242, 243: 243, 244: 244, 245: 245, 246: 246, 247: 247, 248: 248, 249: 249, 250: 250, 251: 251, 252: 252, 253: 253, 254: 254, 255: 255
};
```

#### Tests

```
const arr1 = [{ bar: "bar1" }, { bar: "foo1" }, { qux: 42 }] as const
const arr2 = [{ bar: "bar2" }, { bar: "foo2" }] as const
const arr3 = [{ qux: 42 }] as const

const typedArr1: AssertQuxIsLast<typeof arr1> = arr1
const typedArr2: AssertQuxIsLast<typeof arr2> = arr2 // error (OK)
const typedArr3: AssertQuxIsLast<typeof arr3> = arr3
```

#### Explanations

`AssertQuxIsLast` is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays). Each key `K` in `T` is an index of the form `"0"`,`"1"`,`"2"`, etc. . But this type is a `string`, not a `number`!

In order to assert `Qux` for the last index, we need to convert `K` back to `number` in order to compare it with `T['length']`, which returns the array length `number`. As the compiler doesn't support a dynamic [string to number conversion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223) yet, we have created our own converter with `StringToNumber`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgJygXigbygI0QLigZ2AQEsA7AcygF8BuAWAChRIoBFAVwA8V0oBHLnlLsAtpghJajRgHoZUOPnwTg+NlygAzAPZJgAC2gAbRcChkAJhG7bNUACoAaKNoMSoEIxBERSqqPpwAG7QwNpY0PAIjMzQAIJKKhycAJL4ADKmADz2HpzAvhZqCBBwFtqkRiAKpCAA2gC6AHw8aIxQUHUA0uakUADWECC2Dg14AMpEZOT22gByouIIdQCi+QhwAMbAWV3OhCQUTQ15BaRFUJmEKefWOU3tHVAA-A7dJ9ZnF8mPTy-qnF+TyEEBC0QYfzw9nep0KaiiQNeCIhwKgpFBEnoDCkDFk8lQmzgRk27BMBTUuUQG2qXgoBigIjI7DUAEYYuBoFdgDcrJwcrDzsVSuVKtU4LVGi1UAAKaUAOgVwChAEoUC0gtpiBZVZ84VBZY9OHhxSBHI8FXL2HgyJp3ABVRiq5DqzXax6vO11ABEtPIBi9DUeILBWLxDnGUHKEHwpAA5GZ8OwwGBdAmphQoGE0Yt3LEoJsKmD8MQKmpALwbgFI9s0MOQEcIAd2gieTqf1lmsquEYgkaiTmfCACYAKwANkY1hTCDMecmhxm8xzSFQbRRdX6eAO0zG2e7CCxHQADHgD84WXgWc4B3gB84AMx4W-OAAseCfziHeCHzhHeBHzgA7Hg-7OAAHHgIHOAAnHgkGnkeUAsieCFnshp5XghN4IfeWGni+CFvghH6EaeP4IX+CGARRp5gQhEEIdB9GXvBA5IQOKFsZe6EDphA7Ybxl54QOBHDteX5QAOpESZelEDsB4k0QOdEDgxyl3vBt5IbeKFaXe6G3pht7YYZd54beBG3kRFl3qRt7kbelH2XeNG3nRt4MW5z7wU+SFPihvnPuhT6YU+2Ehc+eFPgRT5EdFz6kU+5FPpRSXPjRT50U+DGZe+8FDkhQ4oQV77oUOmFDth5XvnhQ4EUORF1e+pGju+lFDnJQ40R174MUOsFQCO8EDd+KEjhe-XoSOmEjth03fnhI4ESORFLd+pEjuRI6UZt340SOdEjgxB0AfB-5If+KHnQB6H-ph-7YXdAF4f+BH-kRr0AaR-7kf+lE-QBNH-nR-4McDoHwSBSEgShUOgehIGYSB2GI6BeEgQRIFERjoGkSB5EgZR+OgTRIF0SBDFk1B8GQUhkEobTUHoZBmGQdhLNQXhkEEZBRHc1BpGQeRkGUULUE0ZBdGQQxktwfBiFIYhKEK3B6GIZhiHYercF4YhBGIURetwaRiHkYhlGm3BNGIXRiEMTbp6IeeiH24rLJja7KssmrLIa979vayyussvrQf20bLImyyZuR-blsstbLK2wnaGyyxaGKxxGEq9xaEa-xGHa0JaH68OaFG1JGFm7JaGW4paG26pWGyxpp5aeeOlYSr+ktxrxlYdrZkt-rVlYUbtkt2bjlYZbLkt7bHn4bL3m4Yr-n4SrQW4RrYX4drkW4frsX4UbCW4WbKX4Zb6W4bb2WEbLeWngV55FYRKulY-GuVYR2s1Y-+sNYRI2zVCJmzao-S2XVCK216iRWWQ0yKK1GiRFWk0SIa1mmRbWC0SL6xWmRI260SJm22mRS2e0SK2yOhRWWp1TznXPJdCiKsbp0I1g9Ci2tnp0P1u9CiRsvp0LNn9CiltAZ0NtqDWissIbUUVjDWiKt4bUQ1sjWi2s0bUX1ljWiRtcbUTNoTWilsSbUVthTeistqanlpueem9EVZM2sRrNm9Ftac2sfrXm9EjYC2sWbEW9FLbi2sbbaW4kDzMQiUxdiB4xosS4geHiB4+LJKYoJA8wkDxERYmJFikkDzkRYjJA8ckWIKQPEpA8KkqmXgduJJ29T2Ku1qVxT2tS+K+3qYJAOtTskh3qZJcOtSZLR3qQpOOtSVJJ3Eixa8qcZnsQztxLi2cZl8TztxQShcZnZJLjMyS5duIySrjMhStcZkqQbrxZizdxKtzuXE-S14u53L4r3XigkB53OycPXikkx53JkpPXiCkZ53JUvPISzEl7iV8teVeQkuIb1hXxbeQlBJ71hdkw+QlJIn1hTJc+QkFJX1hSpW+w5mIP3Ek-GlcTSqiR4uVUSj4aWCV-jS7JdVGA4kYAWUghAFAIAQCyHgdQMDYAQHgL0kqWRemoM4CVuAoBeh0NoOVCreACCNFAIK1ATiKHzKWYAfLjVCoQAOMVSqpUqslQOeVVBFVYGVaq7Q2h7X6oUGoflhBTUCrMFSW8Vr+CCF1ZaqgBrvXGukAwH104OQWDiMKlCCRlBTmSGkLkWRYgjCpCyKU5q2SxrNbERNwr0KpqSFwTN2Qc12CpAOAtDaoC1gkAgXQ+oADyXRlR+sFaWpNCBsKVvTdWjItaOS5uFbeJt07GBAA)

Comment: This is an amazingly elaborate answer. Thank you. My conclusion is that for all practical purposes, it would not be worth it.

Comment: @last-child thanks, you're welcome. Updated with a TS 4.0 alternative

Comment: I have to say thanks too, I learned a ton from this answer.

Comment: For the TS 4.2 answer, for this particular problem I think an optional last element is possible with `[...Bar[], Qux] | Bar[]`, would you agree?

Comment: @last-child yes, I like it! Just have tested with above sample data, and it looks good so far. And if you combine it with mentioned generic constrained function, you will be able to preserve fixed-size tuple types instead of arrays. Thanks for the hint, I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since in Javascript the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) are only allowed as the last parameter, the same approach was historically adopted for types in Typescript.
There are longstanding tickets to remove this limitation for types, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25717) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1360), however at the moment, it's still not supported.

Given you [can't strictly define specific-followed-by-rest tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44402762/1470607) in Typescript, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to implement this until the functionality is added to Typescript itself.

Alternatively, you can manually generate a comfortable number of valid type lists in a separate build step, but at that point I doubt the gained value is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is expected to ship with [TS 4.2](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41601).

Example from the [implementing PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41544):

```
function f1(...args: [...string[], number]) {
    const strs = args.slice(0, -1) as string[];
    const num = args[args.length - 1] as number;
    // ...
}

f1(5);
f1('abc', 5);
f1('abc', 'def', 5);
f1('abc', 'def', 5, 6);  // Error
```

Your type will become

```
type Foo = [...Bar[], Qux]
```