# Is there a way to get keys of tuple as numbers?

Tags: typescript, generics, tuples

Consider I have some tuple type:

```
type SomeTuple = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

And now I want to somehow get it's keys as numbers:

```
type SomeTupleKeys<T = SomeTuple> = 0 | 1 | 2;
```

I've tried to use `keyof SomeTuple`, but it returns

> number | "0" | "1" | "2" | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | "concat" | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | ... 14 more ... | "values"

Also I've tried more complex solution

```
type B = (SomeTuple extends infer T ? { [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof T ? K : never } : never)[number];
```

but this one gives strings to me:

> "0" | "1" | "2"

Is there a way to get numbers without hardcoding anything?

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFQK5gDbQLxQNoBEAhgQDRQEBGZFAxgQLoDcAsAFCiRQCCUuA1hBBwAZrEQp0WJlAD0sqADtUCShABOUAD4UADAW0UAjAZ0EATKYpZFAc2AALKwWBwYwdQEs7z1wBk4WiIsdy8fQwIwODBnMFQAZycI2jhFIOBnACs4b2d1CAA3DXiIZ0TPEQyI+IxPWlLquHUqs3jMOoazVEVyyudvABMIAA8AeRErADppqCMAFigEJuhpyYiC4NQIeIJ2TmgAIT4oAAp4JDRMaBHgCEUB+KhvEQ0oZCgAfigAb3wAaSeiiggmEYmQDAAXFAATc7g9gUJRG9PtCoFDFIVXgBfNFKTHqACUeGUqg0zDkCgI+giJgilj24GgAAk4AB3ZBwADiEGAAElgMddIYjIZzKw2EA)

Comment: Why do you need this?  `SomeTuple[1]` and `SomeTuple["1"]` pick out the same element; is there some use case where you need the number and not the string?

Comment: @jcalz, `{ [key in TupleKeys]: { length: key } }` - I have problems with strings in `length` property here...

Comment: "without hardcoding anything"?  probably not in any supported way.  You can a recursive type that grows a tuple until its length matches, but that's more intensive than just having a big tuple like `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,`...`]` floating around that you index into.

Comment: @jcalz, I actually don't know how to make a recursive type...

Comment: That's okay, neither do I.  I mean, I know how to do it in a way that's been [forbidden](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254), but not in a way that's supported.  The big hardcoded tuple is the way I'd go for this, if I needed to do this.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373266/typescript-type-for-an-array-where-last-item-can-have-a-different-type) for a related answer, where the string keys `"0"`, `"1"`, ... of a mapped tuple are converted to a number type to make them comparable to the tuple `length` number property. But I still would call that hacky, so no easy solution without hard-coding here neither.

Comment: @ford04, interesting, but I've actually made the things I wanted by converting numbers to strings: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58563334/4928642. Not a generic approach, but for my usecase it was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) (added in Typescript 4.1):

```
type TupleKeys<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>, Keys extends ReadonlyArray<number> = []> =
    T extends [infer _, ... infer R]
        ? TupleKeys<R, [R['length'], ...Keys]>
        : Keys[number];

type SomeTuple = ["a", "b", "c"];
type SomeTupleKeys = TupleKeys<SomeTuple>; // 0 | 2 | 1
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhA0hEBnAPDKEAewEAdgCYZQBKEAhqQPbGIgCCATmzSFnMQNbF6Ad2IA+ADRQ0mPIRLkqtBk1YcuWYnAC2AIwhtRUALxQA2gF1DRgLAAoKA9iyiZCqYCWxAGb6oAfUkAOmCoTx82KnM7RxioAH5YBGRpbEpJU0pTAHJkYgBzYAALLPMg4JTLaNiHAC4pdAxTTV19cwBuOztQSCgAZXotCHgkaBNTACIacclxnWmocYBjcfau8Gh+weHkhuNEkZSsTaGkiFE2qAB6S6gABigAHygAJkeoAEYgA)

---

Another simpler solution (working with older typescript versions):

```
type TupleKeys<T extends Array<any>> = Exclude<Partial<T>['length'], T['length']>;

type SomeTuple = ["a", "b", "c"];
type SomeTupleKeys = TupleKeys<SomeTuple>; // 0 | 1 | 2
```

Here, by using `Partial` we get the union of tuples of length 0 or 1 or 2 or 3, then we exclude the 3 (the length of original tuple)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFQK5gDbQLxQNoBEAhgQDRQEBGZFAxgQLoDcAsAFDuiRRqYQDSEEAGcAPMigQAHsAgA7ACbCoAQQBOaoiFFE5IAHz6ouAKJTaGVAoiiACkTXAAlkQzj9eAORY5Ac2AAFp4M5MhePv5BDPqsHGxc0PBIvFiCIsY86KlCYkkoWRAxUAD0xVAADFAAPlAAjNVQAExAA)

Comment: Cool, except they both work strange with optional elements. I would've post it in separate answers by the way.

Comment: One more option (keeps optional indexes): `type TupleKeys<T extends Array<any>> = Exclude<Partial<T>['length'], Required<T>['length']>;`