# Convert number type to corresponding string one

Tags: typescript, generics

I have some type with concrete number, for example

```
type Num = 42;
```

Now I want to make converting generic

```
type NumberToString<N> = ... // N as string instead of number
```

So that

```
type A = NumberToString<Num>; // "42"
type B = NumberToString<1>;   // "1"
```

How can I write such converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible for arbitrary numbers.  There's an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15645) ostensibly dedicated to doing math in the type system, but nothing much is happening there as far as I can see.

If you're okay limiting it to *non-negative whole numbers in a "reasonable" range*, you can declare a huge tuple somewhere and do it like this:

```
type HugeTuple = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0]; // as long as you need
type NumToStr<N extends number> = { [K in keyof HugeTuple]: K }[N];

type One = NumToStr<1>; // "1"
type TwoOrFortyTwo = NumToStr<2 | 42> // "2" | "42"
```

So, uh, there you go.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/LAKALgngDgpgBACQK4HMYBUlQDbwLxwDaADADRxkXmU3V1UO2P1Ot2hyfPds8v99BvYaQ5cRQgROlTZzMZxmTlS1bIUq5azTrYbtBrUd2iQXExcOX2Z8casP7-fU+tvDLngF0A3HAD0-nAAhgDOcNgA9gB2KCHhEJFIcNEwMAAmoJCwcABySAC26JEAymAATgA8uXAwAB5gMNHp4dGFAEYw5QB8cAQA3kQA0nAAltFwANYwiQBmiKgYWLheAFxwIwC+hLm+oFnQ8ADyqX15hcVlVQCM3X6BcABE148HOegA7pFH5QBikeVIJ9Imd8kVShVKgAmOAAHzgABYob0Ho8oY84U8ka8QEA)

Comment: I'm actually trying to validate that tuple of tuples from your answer, so it doesn't seem to be a good idea to hardcode one more tuple for that :)

Comment: You can use any tuple, even the one from the other problem, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmKBeKBtVBdANGgDNvHfHVXIog08qMmy2h64gWACgoPCamn6fuBDPoP6M6WNpy5iZo4bJGKhE9pypLRm8ZLUK9WoRgDcUAPSmoAWwCGAa2jWAzlAA2AewB2AcyhOoINzgoDwgIABM2NlBIKAA5OEsYNwBlYAAnAB5YqAgAD2AIDzDnDwSAIwg0gD5kKABvNABpKABLDyh7AIAzWAQMAC4oZoBfVFjjSNZo6AB5ENr4xJT0jIBGKpNzKAAiVe2o8GgYAHc3GbSAdQALNzcwZxRFpNTMgCYoAB8oABZXmq3tq9tp9guVKlAABTwRAtRweADkwFcnh8hUCXiuAEogA).

Comment: [Great!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAzlAvFA2lgugGmwAYDjCTCsjzzSqaprG6nWGKzH32Xuv-WvAXzbNKoiSNripwuYJnzZksZxXrluXAG4oAej1RgKRAEsAdsABcAE1MoAhgCNkAWjPnoAWwcAPdxYQ7hDmAObAABYAsABQoJBQAIIAThAAyg5eEAA8MIQAqoQASgB8GLBQEL7AITZo+VAA-FANVTXmdRXNRVBWUJ4AbhDJvf0QQ8nasRY1yQBmDgDG0ACS5vBIqBvIADIh4REAogCOcA6IKGs2VZXVtWgp6Zk5AN7YANIQIFAWUAAU21Qt3anQsc2GXSgbyw7x+5igAGsvgB7OawXB9WFte6IlFomBNKCwvqDCEAX1GpOSAEosOY4F4nMMtJivlAyYRoZ9vr9ASg6QymclcFgAETIMKRUUsqEfOG4kCo2AIZAoDFE9kwr64dmEADyTgAVhBFsAym8ybEgA)

Comment: By the way, the other way was https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs0LR.png, but it had problem if I miss both zero in last tuple and index of that tuple in list of keys.