# How to Type a Recursive Variadic Tuple

Tags: typescript, recursion, variadic-tuple-types

I have an array of query elements, where each element can be a term or a subquery containing  starting with either "AND" or "OR", and followed by an array of legal query elements, terms or nested subqueries, and so on.

For example, these should all be legal input:

```js
const query1 = "Hello"
const query2 = ["AND", "Hello", "World"]
const query3 = ["OR", ["AND", "Hello", "World"], ["AND", "Hola", "Mundo"]]
```

[**Variadric Tuples**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0-beta/#variadic-tuple-types) in **TS 4.0** should allow you to type the first element of an array and another type for the rest:

```
type IQuery = ["AND" | "OR", ...Array<string>]
const query = ["AND", "Hello", "World"]  // valid
```

[**Recursive Types**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050) in **TS 3.7** should allow you to define an type that uses itself:

```
type IQueryOps = string | Array<IQueryOps>
const query: IQueryOps = ["Hello", "World", ["Hola", "Mundo"]]  // valid
```

But I can't seem to combine the two when the circular type is spread. In this case, each query begins with an operator, and is followed up by either a string or another valid query like this:

```
type IOperator = "AND" | "OR"
type IQuery = [IOperator, ...Array<string | IQuery>]
```

In this case, I get the error:

> Type alias 'IQuery' circularly references itself.(2456)

Is there anyway to type this, even with workarounds, or do I have to unwrap it to the desired level of depth I'd like to support from a types perspective?

#### [Demo in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkgRQK5QE5gGoENUEssAmeAxjALwwDaARAIIByAItTAD4zUDyAStQDQwAdMNqpUWMAB4AziDwA7AOYA+ALrBiAe3myYARxTpseQiQBc8ZGkw58RXKQo0GzAdQASUADZfN-DgDqmqheBNTqoJCwiIZg3FDESKjSuABusBSyCopsMKLiUjHW8YnJaVDKGtq6BsUJSSnpFkXoJQ3l5FQe3r7+1EEhYQI07ppeWH0AskjyBH6qEZHQ8JzQ4iDBnXRMLOxcvEvRVuidlHCraFgbqALCgvkSMnK4SrktYGrAAPRfMAAqURgWC8+GkMAA5O9wTBiLhUIlxiEwDBUFAAGZoKDyYhQMG4EDSbxowQACgATAAWACsADYAJTAKo6ED6WIWLIvHLsd6nfb+Zw7NyeHx+NwDULhYbbVwcUbjKYzObhVRAA)

#### Further Reading

- [Define a type for an array where the first element is more specific than the rest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44402096/1366033)
- [How to create a circularly referenced type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36966444/1366033)

Comment: @Dai Can't tell if you know that it is: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833 and https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14905043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be an instance of the TypeScript design limitation reported in [microsoft/TypeScript#41164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164).  As [mentioned there](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164#issuecomment-712418462),

> Certain circularities are allowed [...] but other circularities aren't, e.g.
>
> ```
> type Identity<T> = T;
> type T3 = Identity<T3>;
> ```
>
> Generic instantiation is *deferred*, so at the point TS analyzes [a] declaration, it can't tell if it's in the `Record` case (would be allowed) or the `Identity` case (would not be allowed). It's only later in the process that we could tell that this is actually OK, but if it wasn't OK, it's "too late" to go back and start complaining about it.

If that's the issue, then while the following should be "okay", it seems that the compiler cannot tell early enough to allow it:

```
// type IQuery = string | ["AND" | "OR", ...Array<IQuery>] error
```

(I changed your definition slightly to allow the `const query1 = "Hello"` line).

---

Luckily, `Array<T>` has an alternative built-in syntax `T[]` which does not seem to be deferred in that manner:

```
type IQuery = string | ["AND" | "OR", ...IQuery[]] // okay
```

And this works:

```
const query1: IQuery = "Hello"
const query2: IQuery = ["AND", "Hello", "World"]
const query3: IQuery = ["OR", ["AND", "Hello", "World"], ["AND", "Hola", "Mundo"]]
const query4: IQuery = ["AND", ["OR", ["AND"]]]; 

const badQuery1: IQuery = 3; // error
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'IQuery'
const badQuery2: IQuery = ["AND", "Hello", 123]; // error
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'IQuery'
const badQuery3: IQuery = 
  ["OR", query1, query2, "then", query3, query4, "if", []]; // error
// Type '[]' is not assignable to type 'IQuery'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQJIEUCusBOlQF5QGdx0BLAOwHNQAfUAbQCIBBAOQBE6rQ6B5AJToBpQAOhEN06AIaQAPMjSYAfAF1QGdAHt0AKChxEqDFlwFi5DvWZsO3PoJFC5hmkpUhQ6gNZStWgMbqSAlAAR3lIAEYALn0wnE4ACVgAGyT1Oj8AoNDDACZox0w4i1YBBOTU0roAdU0kgBM6JQzA8BCwgGZ8g0Lcel5S4rZBOkSUtOGa9HrGwUHK+PUkiUqAWRQSOrSXZqywgBYu2N7GEtmbAZO2FyUAblA3cAALIjxQF-cvLHB1dVAffxaoAARhI6t0IodDHF2nc3GpNFo3AAVGDwADkJBQAFsgRg0W9XiR1K0JHg8EQyCQJECkvBvhBUaA0QVIGidq0QWCwnkYlDjpZ5uVxqBwjl2rd7mB4dpkYyMdjceh8e8iSSyRSqTS6b9dOiWWyAUFOeDOryerRzoJsphwlbucMnrASKVrZB2nbDHthkQAGYDFywqXiBGyvRo5zKwnE0Ck8mU6m0iA6uX6oRaIA)

Comment: We came up with the workaround at the exact same time! But I don't think your theory for why the original apporach didn't work is correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69781309/how-to-type-a-recursive-variadic-tuple/69783118#comment123366291_69783118

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the description of [Recursive Types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050), variadic tuples aren't explicitly supported. I don't know if it counts as one the three types listed below:

> The specific change made by this PR is that type arguments are permitted to make circular references in aliased types of the following kinds:
>
> - Instantiations of generic class and interface types (for example `Array<Foo>`).
> - Array types (for example `Foo[]`).
> - Tuple types (for example `[string, Foo?]`).

I tested this theory by removing the variadic operator `...` from your code:

```
type IOperator = "AND" | "OR"
type IQuery = [IOperator, Array<string | IQuery>] // NO ERROR
```

That change resulted in no error, but it doesn't support the syntax you want.

So I reformulated (and simplified) your code as below, and it works! My theory is that using the variadic operator in combination with a generic class instantiation is not supported, whether intentionally or a bug I don't know.

```
type IOperator = "AND" | "OR"
type IQuery = string | [IOperator, ...IQuery[]]


// examples from your question
const query1: IQuery = "Hello"
const query2: IQuery = ["AND", "Hello", "World"]
const query3: IQuery = ["OR", ["AND", "Hello", "World"], ["AND", "Hola", "Mundo"]]

// deep nesting
const query4: IQuery = ["OR", ["AND", "Hello", ["AND", "Beautiful", "World"]], ["AND", "Hola", "Mundo"]]


//errors
const query5: IQuery = ["OR", ["NOR", "Hello", ["AND", "Beautiful", "World"]], ["AND", "Hola", "Mundo"]]
const query6: IQuery = ["OR", ["AND", 42, ["AND", "Beautiful", "World"]], ["AND", "Hola", "Mundo"]]
```

Comment: Thank you - awesome answer! Looks like jcalz identified the diff which is that *generic instantiation is deferred*, so we can't use `Array<IQuery>` recursively, but we can use the built in type `IQuery[]` (as you pointed out as well)

Comment: @KyleMit I think you missed the part where I proved that `Array<IQuery>` CAN be used recursively. You can test this yourself by removing the variadic operator `...` from your Playground example. So the issues jcalz references don't explain it. As I wrote, it's clearly the combination of *generic instantiation*, the variadic operator and circularity.